# Tagging EC2 instances with Saltstack

Tags: amazon-ec2, salt-stack

I am fairly new to the using saltstack, and am trying to get salt-cloud to tag my EC2 instances during provisioning.  I assume this is something that needs to be done in cloud.profiles.  I have been looking for documentation and specific examples of trying to create tags for EC2 instances when provisioning them.  I have found tagging instances after being creating can be done from the command line with:
    `salt-cloud -a set_tags mymachine tag1=somestuff tag2='Other stuff'`
However I would like these actions to happen automatically when creating the instance.

On a side note, I haven't found the salt documentation to be the most helpful. If there is a tutorial or walkthrough to help familiarize myself more with saltstack, I would appreciate the input.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The ec2.py cloud module looks for 'tags' in the profile.

The following example is cribbed from the above document.

```
mysql_profile:
  provider: ec2
  size: 1024MB
  tags:
    tag1: somestuff
    tag2: "others stuff" 
  [...]
```

Comment: These are Salt grains, not AWS tags

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.  I'll look into it.

Comment: It looks like at least the newest version of salt has code for this by looking for a dict 'tags' in the profile.  Starting at line 3469 in cloud/clouds/ec2.py.

Comment: @AnthonyHayward I overhauled my answer.  Please review.
Link to source: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/cloud/clouds/ec2.py#L3469

Comment: Thanks.  I also corrected my answer, it seems you can put "tag" in the cloud.present state.

Comment: Bearing in mind it will work "when provisioning" new minions. Salt cloud modules are stateless and no change made to the SLS will be applied on next salt run.

Answer (score 1):

The salt.states.cloud docs talk about using "cloud.tagged" Salt state, but it doesn't seem to have been implemented.

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cloud.html#using-states-instead-of-maps-to-deploy-clouds

When creating an instance, it seems you can use the tag property like this:

```
my-server-name:
    cloud.present:
        - name: 'my-server-name'
        #...other properties
        - tag:
            'Env': 'auto-test'
```

This applies tags on creation but won't update them if the instance already exists.  Also, I don't know how to tag the EBS volume in cloud.present.

You can use the Python boto library to re-tag the instances created by SaltStack and to tag EBS volumes.  Example code below - works for instances and EBS volumes.

```
def find_instance(instanceName, region):
    boto_ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region)
    instances = boto_ec2.get_only_instances()
    for instance in instances:
        if instance.tags.get("Name", None) == instanceName:
            return instance
    return None



def ensure_instance_tags(instance, region, tags):
    newTags = {}    

    for tagName in tags:
        if instance.tags.get(tagName, None) != tags[tagName]:
            newTags[tagName] = tags[tagName]

    if bool(newTags):
        sys.stdout.write("Updating tags for instance " + instance.id + "\n")
        boto_ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region)
        boto_ec2.create_tags(instance.id, newTags)
```